# Python how to make a function that will open each file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with a list of .txt files:

```
- blablablabla.txt
- 1235654.txt , etc
```

I need to write a function. First request to the function will open first .txt file and copy all the text. 
Second request - will open second .txt file from a folder and copy all the text and so on.

Working Code #1:

```
import os, glob

filenames = []

for d, dirs, files in os.walk('./testtxt'):
    for f in files:
        print (f)
        filenames.append(f)
```

This code Shows the list of files inside folder.

Working code #2:

```
import copy

def printtext(swefile):
    for row in swefile:
        print(row)
text = open("test.txt","r",encoding='utf-8').readlines()
text2 = copy.copy(text)
printtext(text)
```

This one copy text inside .txt document. How to connect those 2 codes and make that pain in ass function?

Comment: You read a line, and get a string. That string is a filename. Pass THAT to printtext(filename), and let it call open.

Comment: Can you show me code please? I wanted to put filenames (the list) into def and place it into "text = open('Here', r...) at first haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
yourpath = 'path'

import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        stuff
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        stuff
```